# Google Charts API, scatter plot with 4 plots with 4000 points each kills HTTPD

Tags: php, mysql, apache, api, charts

I have a scatter plot graph that pulls 4 sets of data from a local MySQL server with 4000+ points each and graphs them all on one graph.
HTTPD gets crushed and although it successfully graphs them, takes about 3 minutes to do so. Is this expected and is there a way to optimize the charting?
The machine running MySQL and Apache is an i7 4770K with 32gb of ram and a 250gb SSD running Ubuntu 14.04
Since it's a single session, HTTPD is confined to one core.

Is this just something I have to look into optimizing my php for or is a graph like this going to take awhile to load no matter what when displaying it in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and dirty way to test which component is doing the 'killing' is to temporarily change all charts on your page to the type 'table'.

If this loads without a hitch then it is likely the client browser that has an issue drawing all the points needed to represent the data.

If you still experience slowness it would then indicate the issue is either the web server, the MySQL server, or the connection between them.